# IntelliJ Gradle task execution cannot resolve local build script references

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build-script

I just understood how buildscript works and I've made a basic script that just puts kotlin inside any subproject with

```
`kotlin-conventions`
```

My gradle multiproject is setup like this:

```
project
 ├─ acq
 |  ├─ build.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
 ├─ acs
 |  ├─ build.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
 ├─ acs-client
 |  ├─ build.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
 ├─ buildSrc
 |  ├─ src
 |  |  ├─ main
 |  |  |  ├─ kotlin
 |  |  |  |  ├─ containerized-app.gradle.kts
 |  |  |  |  ├─ kotlin-conventions.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ build.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
 ├─ core
 |  ├─ build.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
 ├─ sp
 |  ├─ build.gradle.kts
 |  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
```

`project/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/kotlin-conventions.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`project/buildScr/build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20")
    implementation("com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:3.3.1")
}
```

`project/acq/build.gradle.kts`

```
val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project

plugins {
    `kotlin-conventions`
    `containerized-app`
}

group = "be.rm.secu.tp2"
version = "0.0.1"

application {
    mainClass.set("be.rm.secu.tp2.acq.ApplicationKt")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
}
```

(You can go to the [github repository](https://github.com/Florent-Git/SecurityTP2/tree/buildscript) to get the full code, although I cannot promise that the code won't change in the future)

The problem I'm having, is that when I run gradlew from a CLI (WSL 2.0, Java 17.0.5-tem, Gradle 7.4.2), everything is fine and this is the output:
[image: Working output]

But, when I'm executing the task on IntelliJ, it says that they cannot resolve my buildscript...
[image: Error output]

I don't really understand why is this happening, I am guessing this is an IntelliJ problem.

I tried searching for a similar case, although I couldn't find anything. I tried invalidating caches, removing caches. Changing environment (CMD, PowerShell, WSL), removing .gradle(s), removing .idea...

I could try working with gradle on CLI and IntelliJ as an IDE, but this is not really efficient, as I will surely rely on the IntelliJ debugger in the future...

Thanks !

Comment: I guess Intellij uses not ./gradlew, since it's for Unix, but ./gradlew.bat or something. Can you try running that with gradlew.bat or with the downloaded graldle.exe directly? It might have something to do with the fact, that Intellij uses Windows version

Comment: Have you configured IntelliJ to delegate Gradle actions to the Gradle wrapper? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle

Comment: @VitalyChura Either gradlew, gradlew.bat nor C:\gradle\...\gradle.bat work...

Comment: @aSemy I've tried the three configuration they allow me (use gradle from:) and nothing changes... Even changing JDK doesn't change anything :/